# How do I get carouFredSel to play again after pause immediate (custom events)?

Tags: jquery, configuration, caroufredsel

I'm testing different configurations trying to create the desired experience. I'm using a continuous scroll configuration and pausing it at page load. Then I have previous and next buttons. I have the buttons working on hover. So hover over scrolls it in that direction, and hover off pauses it.

The problem is when I change it to pause immediately. It doesn't play again next time I hover over.

Here's an excerpt from the code where it works, but is not immediate:

```
.find('.prev').hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('ul')
        .trigger('configuration', ['direction', 'right'])
        .trigger('play');
}, function() {
    $(this).parent().find('ul').trigger('pause');
})
```

And here is the code for the immediate pause:

```
.find('.prev').hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('ul')
        .trigger('configuration', ['direction', 'right'])
        .trigger('play');
}, function() {
    $(this).parent().find('ul').trigger('pause', true); //immediate pause
})
```

I've tried many different parameter combinations for both play and pause, but nothing gets the desired result - pause/resume immediately. It plays the first time, but then never again.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/toxalot/4vN2z/) with full code example.

What am I missing?

Comment: I would like to know too, I bang my head for hours with the same problem you experience now and I couldn't figure it out. The plugin just likes to finish it's animation before proceeding to the next one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To play again after an immediate pause, trigger the resume event instead of the play event.

```
.trigger('resume')
```

Note that it will finish its transition when it resumes. It *has* to finish the transition at some point. Depending on other settings, this may or may not be noticeable.

To finish the transition immediately, trigger the finish event.

```
.trigger('finish')
```

Depending on other settings, this may make it look a bit "glitchy", but at least it doesn't give the impression that the buttons aren't working.

Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/toxalot/D2ZwN/) for two variations of continuous scroll. One pauses immediately and then resumes on hover. The other finishes immediately and then speeds up on hover.